# Visual Studio 2010 Creating Packages/Folders in project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am new to `Visual Studio 2010 C++`, I am trying to create packages in my project like we do in `Java Eclipse` but to my surprise the only option I found available was `Creating a Folder` so I selected that and created several folders added my classes to them then I tried `including` my header files in the folders I had created but it keeps giving me an error to hat I cannot locate the file, I checked in the Project directory and the folders are not in there but very visible and editable from `Visual studio`, I tried manually adding a folder with my classes from windows explore and still could not locate them in `VC`

Comment: Folders in the Solution Explorer are virtual and are  not tied to filesystem folders.

Comment: so how to I create a folder and add files that actually exist to it?

Comment: Create folders using explorer. And no they will not keep the structure in Solution Explorer. It is not a flilesystem view.

Comment: its worked tho I cannot see the folders in my project

Comment: There should be an option "Show all files" in Solution explorer Toolbar if you choose a project node (don't remember if VS2010 has it already). P.S. No need to use 6 years old version, check [Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx) it's much better in every aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is organized slightly different than in Eclipse.

With Visual Studio, you create a ***solution*** (one directory) in which you will create [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9kd355%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23x5fk78%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ***projects*** (either in the solution's directory, or in one or several subdirectories.  I you have in your components a shared library for example, you would put in a separate project.

The source files in each project are [organized in the same directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6fatbd5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  If you use folders in a project, these are virtual and not materialized in the OS directories.

***Remark:*** If you really want to organise project files within "hard" subdirectories, you can always force the directory in the item creation dialog.  This is particularly practical if you add to a visual studio projects existing items stored according to a more complex OS structure.  Unfortunately such a directory structure is not at all displayed in the solution explorer, so it is somewhat confusing.

Comment: am going to have a hard time getting used to this, one more thing, when I create a directory in my project using explore I cannot locate the item without using absolute path

Comment: I think it's worth trying to get used to it.  If you really can't, there is perhaps a work-around:  in the solution explorer window, there should be a button/icon called "view all files" (I think it was already there in VS2010 but not 100% sure).  If you click on it, VS will show all the files structured according to os directories.  But it's only a workaround : it doesn't show any longer the virtual folders, and in addition it shows plenty of non-source files. Which is also confusing